# Network adapter Could Not Established The Connection IN SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying connect the oracle database using SQL Developer tools but It showing me:

> IO ERRORS: Network adapter Could Not Established The Connection

I Started the `OracleXETNSListner` service from service.msc: it's running.

I also used the `lsnrctl start` command, which couldn't start the listener either.

And one more thing: I used `sqlplus` command prompt: it works fine (also gets connected database)

Thanks in advance...

this is my Tnsname.ora file
**my tnsname file located at C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora**

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = HP-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

Comment: What are the connection parameters you use when connecting via SQLDeveloper, i.e. the host name, port, SID, etc.?

Comment: host name is : localhost
port : 1521
& SID is : XE

Comment: Your tnsnames file has an entry with host name - HP-PC, did you try connecting using this as the host name? Based on this it seems that the Oracle database is running on your PC/machine and the client i.e. SQL Developer is also running on the same machine, is that right?